# How to paste \ to a string in R?

Tags: r, string, paste

I'm want to add \ to a string in R like this:

`paste("23", "\%", sep = "")`

Such that the string reads: `"23\%"`

But I get the error: `Error: '\%' is an unrecognized escape in character string starting ""\%"`

Any idea on to correct this?

Thank you!

Comment: just add another \

Comment: See ?Quotes for more

Comment: Also see https://xkcd.com/1638/

Comment: Yes, but it prints as "23\\%", not "23\%" I need to copy and paste it into another document.

Comment: Use `cat` instead of `print`.